# Processing Abandoned when Uploading Audio Recording Video to YouTube

Tags: audio, video, file-upload, youtube, video-processing

I keep getting the error: "processing abandoned, this video could not be processed" whenever I try to upload a 107 minute video of an audio recording (just myself rambling thoughts into a microphone the entire time, just a black screen for video). The original audio file is .m4a, and I am trying to convert it into a video file to upload to YouTube. I have tried all the methods that I could find mentioned online, and every time I still get the exact same error. I have tried:

- converting from .m4a to .mp4 using VLC and uploading the .mp4
- converting from .m4a to .MOV using VLC and uploading the .MOV
- converting from .m4a to .mp4 using various online conversion tools and uploading the .mp4
- converting from .m4a to .MOV using various online conversion tools and uploading the .MOV
- converting from .m4a to .mp3 using various online conversion tools, then converting from .mp3 to both .mp4 and .MOV and uploading the .mp4 and .MOV
- verifying my youtube account and enabling the verification feature eligibility settings in the youtube creator studio to allow uploads longer than 15 minutes
- re-uploading the same file after the processing failed to try and restart the process
- trying different browsers

I also tried exporting the video file again using the default video editor on Windows (the only video editor I have), but I couldn't upload either the audio file (not an option to choose as an import file type) or the video files I created (gave error: "these files have properties that can't be read". I don't know why this error came up either, but maybe it's because the file is corrupted? This wouldn't make sense to me though because I'm able to play it fine (all file types) in the windows default player, VLC, and Audacity. I was able to convert the audio into the video files in VLC too, so I don't know why I can't do the same in the windows default editor.

I realize that similar questions have been asked before on here, but none actually give a solution that works for my problem. Any insight into why I may be having this problem, and how I may be able to solve it, would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youtube doesn't allow audio-only uploads. They expect you to have some sort of video content (which is why you'll see album art on music-only uploads). You'll need some sort of video content. [Shotcut](https://shotcut.org/) is a free video editor that may help you out. Or if you're willing to use the command line [ffmpeg can help you out](https://superuser.com/questions/98980/creating-video-with-audio-and-still-image-for-youtube)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Also, does this mean that even though I converted the audio file into a video format (.mp4, .MOV), it is still treated as just audio? If so, does this mean that the black screen I see when I play the video isn't actually the image of the video, but rather just a lack of video data? I thought that my converters created a black video with the audio playing over it, but maybe that's incorrect?

Comment: I can't say for certain, but most likely the black video is just what they show by default. MP4 and MOV are container formats, they can hold arbitrary numbers of video, audio and subtitle streams